# How to upload a folder to blob storage using SAS URI in storage explorer

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBsQN.png)I'm trying to upload a folder to blob container using storage explorer via SAS URI, but the upload is failing for folder & files. How can I achieve that ? When I connect to blob storage using account name and key it works fine, but not with SAS URI.

Comment: well, does the SAS have proper permissions to do what you want to?

Comment: Hey @kunal,Can you please post the error message which you are getting?  That would help us in identifying the cause. Also the key has admin access on the account whereas the sas is a controlled access with specific permission. So based on your input, we might be missing some permission in the sas

Comment: How did you upload files with SAS URI and login your Storage account in Storage explorer?  We need more details about the error.

Comment: I think i have 
Read, Write, Delete, Delete version, List, Add, Create Permissions. I'm not getting any error in storage explorer. It says upload failed. that's it.

Comment: Hi @Kunal Sinha, Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created several tests and all succeeded with SAS URI.
[image]

I think you should check a few places:

1. According to your screen shot. Maybe your SAS key has expired?
   [image]
2. The `URI` configuration. We should concat the `connect string` and the  `SAS token`.
   [image]

The configuration is as follows:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Kunal Sinha, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the permissions allotted to SAS and also the expiry date, there can be two cases here: one you may not have adequate access to upload and second the SAS might have expired.

If this is a one time activity and then you can use AzCopy tool as well to upload files to blob storage.